# Error While inserting username and pass word into database

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell

I am trying to insert following data in psql and its showing me weird error.

```
      -bash-4.1$ psql -t -d mydb -c 'insert into ftp_mgr (id, info) values("192.168.1.12",       '{"username": "Administrator", "password": "abc456$", "serverAddr":"192.168.1.12"}');'

      psql: warning: extra command-line argument "password:" ignored
      psql: warning: extra command-line argument "abc456$," ignored
      psql: warning: extra command-line argument "serverAddr:192.168.1.12});" ignored
      psql: FATAL:  role "Administrator," does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with PostgreSQL. It's a shell quoting problem.

You *cannot nest single quotes* in bash. So this:

```
'insert into ftp_mgr (id, info) values("192.168.1.12",       '{"username": "Administrator", "password": "abc456$", "serverAddr":"192.168.1.12"}');'
```

is read up to:

```
'insert ...'{
```

and the `{` is *not part of the quoted string. So the shell tries to intepret `{"username": "Administrator", "password": "abc456$", "serverAddr":"192.168.1.12"}` as a shell command.

---

The simplest thing to do here is to use a quoted here-document to avoid the need to deal with `'` literal quoting mixing with the shell's quoting:

```
psql -t -d mydb <<'__END__'
insert into ftp_mgr (id, info) values
("192.168.1.12", '{"username": "Administrator", "password": "abc456$", "serverAddr":"192.168.1.12"}');
__END__
```

The quotes around the here-document tag are *important*. If you leave them out then bash still looks for and replaces `$variable` strings, etc, within the here-document text. That can be really handy, but it's clearly not what you want in this case.

---

if you must do it with `-c` you have a couple of options:

Use the shell's string concatenation. Whenever you want a single-quote, end the current single quoted string, write `"'"`, and open a new single quoted string. So you'd write:

```
'insert ... values(..., '"'"'{"....
```

Confusing to read, isn't it? The first `'` ends the single-quoted shell string. Then `"'"` is a single quote, quoted by double quotes that're consumed by the shell. Then the next `'` begins a new single-quoted string.

That's horrible to read, and it's not much better written as:

```
'insert ... values(..., '\''{"....
```

so personally, when I need single quotes within an argument string I either double-quote the whole string and backslash-escape shell metacharacters:

```
  "insert into ftp_mgr (id, info) values(\"192.168.1.12\", '{\"username\": \"Administrator\", \"password\": \"abc456\$\", \"serverAddr\":\"192.168.1.12\"}');"
```

... or where possible I use a quoted here-document to get around the whole horrifying mess.

---

My preference is to just avoid the shell for this kind of thing and use a simple Python script.

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=postgres')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute(r'insert into ftp_mgr (id, info) values(%s, %s);', (
     r'192.168.1.12',
     r'{"username": "Administrator", "password": "abc456$", "serverAddr":"192.168.1.12"}'
   ))
```

Python's support for raw-strings (`r''`), triple quote strings (`"""`), etc make this sort of thing much easier.